# how to process dir string into smaller dir string

Tags: php

this is a weird question to ask , i dont know if i can phrase it correctly but lets say i have a string "/lib/../" and its a valid dir , now its not easy to read and the clean view of it should be "/" , so is there a way i can process "/lib/../" into "/"

one way i though is to create an array by exploding the non clean dir string by the '/' and it will give me 2 (or more depending on the string) values "lib and .." i can then check in a foreach loop with a key if a '..' exists then it will just delete the '..' and the value before it

though i would like to see if anyone has a better idea (especially if there is already a feature that does that)

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: im not asking to solve it i gave a potential way to solve it , but im just asking if there is a function that does it , im not asking for code , just a simple "no i think your idea is good" or "you might wanna check this feature in php"

Comment: Why you want to extract only `/` from this path? What if you have string `/lib/..`?

Comment: "I would like to see if anyone has a better idea" questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

i went to creating my own fix and this code does it

```
function hahaPathGoFix($f){
$letsee = explode('/',$f);
foreach ($letsee as $key => $sd){
if ($sd == '..'){
unset($letsee[$key]);
unset($letsee[$key-1]);
}
}
foreach ($letsee as $fin){
echo '/'.$fin;
}
}
```

now the only problem is that its adding an extra / in the beggining but that could be fixed by observing the values in the array then i believe i just have to delete the first value (why idk but it appears to work) so i just add a

```
unset($letsee[0]);
```

between the foreach loops

Answer (score -1):

I think Php realpath function is what you want.

Comment: i tried it but it seems to not work constantly , although i think in a normal case it would work